# 'Can only use -performBlock: on an NSManagedObjectContext that was created with a queue.' Error

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, crash, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I use `NSManagedObjectContext performBlock{}`
But,
My app always crash here

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can only use -performBlock: on an NSManagedObjectContext that was created with a queue.'

How to know the right thread about the `NSManagedObjectContext`.
The create `NSManagedObjectContext` code is here

```
Person *aPerson = (Person *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:[CoreDataManager sharedInstance].managedObjectContext];
```

Please give some comments

Comment: Why do you want to know the thread?

Comment: The error seams that we need know the thread.

Comment: No, the error talks about queues, not threads. Did you read the multithreading programming guide fr Core Data?

Comment: Yeh, may be I need do some research. Just mark it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your ManagedObjectContext like this

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc]
                     initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
```

`NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` creates a context that is associated with the main dispatch queue and thus the main thread. You could use such a context to link it to objects that are required to run on the main thread, for example UI elements.

`NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` creates and manages a private dispatch queue to operate on. You must use the new methods performBlock: or performBlockAndWait:. The context will then execute the passed blocks on its own private queue.

Finally, `NSConfinementConcurrencyType` is the default type and can be used only within the thread where it has been created.

Answer (score 0):

The error does not say that you are using the wrong thread. It says that you can use `-performBlock:` only on contexts that are created with a queue. As described in the class reference of [`NSManagedObjectContext`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/)/Concurrency, this are only the contexts that are created with one of the options `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` or `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` set.

> You use contexts using the queue-based concurrency types in conjunction with performBlock: and performBlockAndWait:.